# bash - how to create multiple connections simultaneously in one script

Tags: bash

I am trying to put together a simple bash script to fire a selection of queries at a database simultaneously for load testing purposes.

So far I have a file called "input_file" that contains the following:

```
select sleep(10);
select sleep(11);
select sleep(12);
select sleep(13);
select sleep(14);
select sleep(15);
select sleep(16);
select sleep(17);
select sleep(18);
select sleep(19);
select sleep(20);
```

I then have the following code:

```
IFS=$'\n'
for line in $(cat input_file)
do
{
    mysql -S[socket] -u[username] -p[password] -e${line}
}
done
```

But instead of running the queries simultaneously, it runs them one at a time, and waits for each query to finish before starting the next one. I want it to start the first query, then move on without waiting for it to finish, so that I end up with all the queries running at the same time.

I have seen various posts about people who have the opposite problem, but I can't seem to get any of their "wrong" examples to work.

Comment: Use `&` to execute the `mysql` in background.

Comment: There are applications designed to load test databases or http/tcp services with multiple connections, and your best solution is to use one of those.  However, if you insist on coding it yourself with shell commands/scripts, look into GNU parallels.

Comment: I use mysqlslap quite extensively, but it doesn't work for this specific use case (as far as I can tell), e.g. multiple connections all running a single (but different) query simultaneously, only multiple connections running the same batch of queries one after the other.

Comment: "Use & to execute the mysql in background" - as simple as that. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

In the comments section it was already mentioned that you can add `&` to the end of the mysql command to make it run in the background. I wanted to suggest another approach using GNU `xargs`:

```
cat input_file | xargs --no-run-if-empty --delimiter '\n' --max-procs 0 -I '{}' mysql -S[socket] -u[username] -p[password] -e'{}'

# Or with short flags...
xargs -r -d '\n' -P 0 -I '{}' mysql -S[socket] -u[username] -p[password] -e'{}' < input_file

# Or letting xargs open the file and leave its stdin alone...
xargs --arg-file input_file -r -d '\n' -P 0 -I '{}' mysql -S[socket] -u[username] -p[password] -e'{}'
```

- `-r` / `--no-run-if-empty` to avoid running mysql if the input is empty.
- `--delimiter '\n'` / `-d '\n'` - Input  items are terminated by a new line. When processing the input, quotes and backslash are not special; every character in the input is taken literally. Without this option, it won't work properly in the input contains backslashes or quotes (common in SQL code)."
- `-P max-procs` / `--max-procs=max-procs` - Run up to max-procs processes at a time; the default is 1. If max-procs is 0, xargs will run as many processes as possible at a time.
- `-I replace-str` - Replace  occurrences of replace-str in the initial-arguments with names read from the input.
- `-a file` / `--arg-file file` - read the arguments from the specified file instead of stdin.

The advantage of using GNU `xargs` is that you can limit the number of concurrent processes by setting `<max-procs>` parameter in `-P` to any number other than 0. In that case, if your input is very long and too many concurrent processes might hammer the server, you can limit the concurrency.